# CSS precedence not working as expected with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am defining a custom class to override the color property for a div element using a custom class **navbar-brand-custom**. I learned that the style defined later always takes priority over others so the Project Name should be appearing in blue as defined in the custom CSS. But somehow I dont see that happening. Can you please see if I am missing anything.

**External CSS:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

**Internal CSS:**

```
.navbar-brand-custom
{
  color:blue;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
         <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-custom" href="#" >Project name</a>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have created the scenario here. The 'Project Name' is still in it default color, and not blue in color.
https://jsfiddle.net/u3nh21uL/

Comment: Is the internal CSS file included below bootstrap.css?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade) to know about cascading preference.

Comment: I'm doing this and it's still not working.  No idea why when I remove bootstrap.min.css it works????

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.navbar-header a.navbar-brand-custom
{
  color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap's styling dictates this

```
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #777;
}
```

It's just a matter of improving your selector for added specificity

```
 .navbar-brand.navbar-brand-custom    {
  color:blue;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/u3nh21uL/1/)

Comment: Thanks! That works. But still wondering why it does't work when not so specific. I mean why is the external style still taking precedence

Comment: There still seems to be a little problem. I have specified a hover style to be blue. Thats just fine. However a right click on the Project Name is causing it to behave strangely. It just goes back and assumes it's dictated color when right clicked.

Comment: Right click? That not allowed for in CSS...I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: I missed to include this: https://jsfiddle.net/u3nh21uL/4/ 
Just right click on the Project Name and you will see that the blue color wont stay

Comment: As I said, **right click** is not something that HTML deals with but I suspect that's the `:focus`pseudo-class - https://jsfiddle.net/u3nh21uL/5/